# Replace set timeout in typescript. Wavesurfer.js

Tags: angular, typescript, settimeout, wavesurfer.js

I have a function where I change the source for the wavesurfer.js audio file, then want to play the song with the newly loaded audio file.  Currently, my code is running how I want it to, but I feel like there has to be a better way of doing this.

Here is my function.

```
changeAudioFile(i){
   let newSong = 'Link to a different File'
   this.ws.load(newSong);

   setTimeout(() => {
     this.ws.play()
   }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Your code won't work if the song doesn't load in 1 sec. Aren't there any events to listen to for when a file has finished loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can isten for the `ready` event

```
this.ws.on('ready',() => {
    this.ws.play()
});
```

[Documentation](https://wavesurfer-js.org/docs/events.html)